# Algorithm for all the possible positions of dots between letters

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations, probability

Say I have a word like "welcome", I want to insert a full-stops between the letters of the word.
So it would be "welcome", "w.elcome", we.lcome",...... Until it reaches "w.e.l.c.o.m.e".

I need an algorithm that will give me all the possible combinations of letters and full-stops for any given word.

Comment: nobody will write code for you in this community. Try to write yourself

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great advice, but I don't want anyone to write a code for me. I'm a beginner and I'm still trying to teach myself how to program. I though of this problem and tried to figure it out myself but I couldn't. So I thought someone might tell me how to solve it; Give me an insight that will help me write the code. But anyway thanks for your criticism, you've been of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a set `S` containing all the possible positions of `.`. Now, Length of the set `S` would be `lengthOfTheString - 1`.

Now you just need to find all possible subsets of set `S` and while processing each of them, You can mark the positions present in the subset as `.`.

[How to generate a powerset](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/).

This way you can generate all the possible combinations.

```
Ex. String : "abc"

a b c
 ^ ^
 1 2

Subsets :
{}       abc
{1}      a.bc
{2}      ab.c
{1,2}    a.b.c
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps a lot.